# Retrieve value from span section with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the 'Sold for' value (i.e. $1,040,000) and 'Rating value' (i.e. $640,000) from the below piece of html code.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
html = '''
              <div class="padb-listing-id">
               <span>
                Listing ID:
               </span>
               804244
              </div>
              <div class="padb-property-value">
               <span>
                Sold for:
               </span>
               $1,040,000
              </div>
              <div class="padb-property-rating-value">
               <span>
                Rating Value:
               </span>
               $640,000
               <span class="padb-rating-date">
                (July '17)
               </span>
              </div>
             '''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

listing_id = soup.find('div', class_='padb-listing-id').text
value = soup.find('div', class_='padb-property_value')
rating_value = soup.find('div', class_='padb-property-rating-value').text
print(f'{listing_id}Price: {value}{rating_value}')
```

which returns this output:

```
        Listing ID:
       
       804244
      Price: None

        Rating Value:
       
       $640,000
       
        (July '17)
```

It brings back 'None' for the 'Sold for' value and I don't know how to fix it. I've looked up a few posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963235/how-to-retrieve-data-from-html-between-span-and-span), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729085/retrieve-span-value), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133759/how-to-get-text-from-span-tag-in-beautifulsoup) but none of these have worked for me.

I'm new to BeautifulSoup and html so would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!!

P.s.
When I add '.text' to the 'value' code I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. Thought I add this here in case anyone wonders why the 'value' code is different from the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a typo in `value = soup.find('div', class_='padb-property-value')`

Set class name to:

```
padb-property-value
```

And add `.text`:

```
value = soup.find('div', class_='padb-property-value').text
```

---

**Just in case**

If you only want the value of the price you can do the following things.

1. Split your actually value:

   ```
   soup.find('div', class_='padb-property-value').text.split()[-1]
   ```
2. Specify your selection:

   ```
   soup.find('div', class_='padb-property-value').contents[2].strip()
   ```

Comment: Thanks!! How silly of me, sorry for not spotting that myself. Thanks for the extra tips as well! The output looks much nicer now!!

Comment: Happy to help - Sometimes I also do not see the wood for the trees ... :)